# Finding the co-efficient of deuteron wave function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, renormalization

[image]

This is the deuteron potential well. The wave functions are given by $$u_{I}(r)=Asin( k_{1}r)  $$ $$u_{II}(r)=C e^{- k_{2} r  } $$

We have to find the coefficients A an C using continuity and normalization. I applied normalization $$\int_o^ \infty   |u|^{2}  dr =1 $$
  $$ \Rightarrow  \int  |u_{I}|  ^2 +\int  |u_{II}|  ^2=1 $$

Is it the right step to do? If so I did the algebra. $A^2$ turns out to be very complicated.

Comment: The short answer is yes. It is quite complicated, but the algebra is like you have done doable. Another way, if you don't need to normalise the wavefunction, is to simply take the wavefunctions equal to each other at the boundary and then choose a value for A, say 1, calculating C from that.

I hope to provide a full answer however as no one has responded to this and I do not currently have time I have at least put this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The integration measure is incorrect (if you work not in $1D$ space). In 3D, $\mathrm{d} V= 4 \pi r^2 \mathrm{d} r$. You also have to find $k_1$ and $k_2$ solving the Schroedinger equation in two domains with different values of constant potential.